# Как красиво получить последний элемент массива?

Tags: java, массивы, list, java-8, java-stream

Когда надо получить последний элемент массива, то как правило используется классическая конструкция:

```java
int a = array[array.length - 1];
```

Я называю её классической, потому что я встречал её в своих учебных материалах очень часто, и она первая приходит на ум, когда мне надо получить последний элемент массива.

Однако, недавно я увидел, что она порождает проблему: массив может быть пустым и попытка получить последний элемент породит **IndexOutOfBoundException**. Появляются дополнительные проверки:

```java
int length = array.length;
int a;
if (length != 0) {
    a = array[length - 1];
} else {
    a = 0; // для примера, логика обработки данной ситуации может быть и другой
}
```

Можно использовать Stream API, и сделать такую конструкцию:

```java
Optional<Integer> a = list.stream().reduce((a, a1) -> a1);
```

Но она тоже выглядит странно. Почему в List нет метода `getLast()`, как в LinkedList? Почему в Stream API отсутствует функция `last()`, тогда как там есть функция `first()`?

Каковы исторические / технические причины отсутствия метода `last()` в интерфейсе List и Stream API, и как можно красиво получать последний элемент списка?

Comment: я не понял, в чем проблема то с этим кодом? `int a = array[array.length - 1];` Зачем тут какие то стримы и прочее? Если вы ожидаете, что массив будет не пустой, а кто то передаст его как пустой - тот себе будет сам буратиной, и ваш код должен упасть.

Comment: а вот если вам не массив, а null передадут, тоже будете стримы запускать?

Comment: Моя точка зрения - вы решаете выдуманную проблему, проблему, которой нет в природе.

Comment: "она порождает проблему: массив может быть пустым и попытка получить последний элемент породит IndexOutOfBoundException" --- в таком случае, если массив пустой - просто товарисчу выкидываем ошибку, что ожидаем не пустой массив. тчк

Comment: @tym32167 да, если передадут null, то я буду запускать стрим. Специально для этого есть Optional.ofNullable, который позволяет не отклоняться от функционального стиля.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский , а если массив может быть пустым и это нормально? Строить бизнес-логику на выбрасывании исключений, это в принципе нонсенс.

Comment: @Zhenyria окей. то есть ты хочешь получить последний элемент массива из пустого массива и это для тебя норма....понятно...логично...

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский , подразумевается, что пустой массив - это нормально. Например надо получить массив с кредитами человека и вытащить из него последний кредит. Если у человека нет кредитов - ну это не ошибка, это штатная ситуация, а массив будет пустым. Тут исключение бросать действительно неправильно будет

Comment: Если функция принимает в себя не то, что ожидает - функция должна сругнуться, а не промолчать..... Если ожидается, что элемент может быть пустым, то перед взятием данных из него надо проверять на пустоту - это нормально. Можно выделить в отдельный метод и получится что-то типа `if (user.hasCredits()) { Credit credit = user.getLastCredit() }`.  или `if (!user.hasCredits()) return;`. Бояться этого не надо. Просто перевести в человекочитаемый вид.

Comment: Вы что то с чем то путаете. Вы думаете, со если заменить одно условие на стримы и optional, то код станет красивее, но это не так. Если ваша функция ожидает непустой массив, то на пустом массиве она должна упасть. Если она учитывает пустой массив, то она должна делать это явно, то есть там должно быть условие `if (array.len == 0) …`, и это явно покажет логику функции. Нет никакого смысла писать что то сложнее, чем это.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `Java 21` был внедрён интерфейс `SequencedCollection`, который призван решить [две проблемы](https://www.baeldung.com/java-21-sequenced-collections#motivation):

1. Слишком общий интерфейс `Collection`.
2. Разные способа получения одних и тех же элементов в разных коллекциях.

Теперь у реализаций интерфейса `List` *(который в данный момент наследует интерфейс `SequencedCollection`)*, появился метод `getLast`, который возвращает последний элемент списка:

```
// java 21 code

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
System.out.println(list.getLast()); // 2 in output
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможны варианты с использованием тернарного оператора:

```java
// последний элемент непустого массива
public static Optional<Integer> getLast(int ... arr) {
    return null == arr || 0 == arr.length ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(arr[arr.length - 1]);
}
```

---

*Почему в `List` нет метода `getLast()`, как в `LinkedList`?*
У списков есть `ListIterator`, для которого можно установить начало итерации в конец списка и вернуть предыдущий элемент [`ListIterator::previous`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#previous--):

```java
public static Optional<Integer> getLast(List<Integer> list) {
    return null == list || list.isEmpty() ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(list.listIterator(list.size()).previous());
}
```

Для списка также есть вариант с использованием `Optional::flatMap` +  `Stream::skip`:

```java
public static Optional<Integer> getLast(List<Integer> list) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(list).flatMap(in -> in.stream().skip(Math.max(0, in.size() - 1)).findFirst());
}
```

В последнем случае можно использовать и вариант со `Stream::reduce`, как наиболее лаконичный (но не производительный):

```java
public static Optional<Integer> getLast(List<Integer> list) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(list).flatMap(in -> in.stream().reduce((a, b) -> b));
}
```

---

Ещё один способ: тернарный оператор + `Stream::skip`:

```java
public static Optional<Integer> getLast(List<Integer> list) {
    return null == list || list.isEmpty() ? Optional.empty() : list.stream().skip(list.size() - 1).findFirst();
}
```